# Does Spring allow get name of bean in factory method?

Tags: java, spring, methods

I have like:

```
<bean id="beansInst" factory="beanFactory" factory-method="getInstance" />
```

In factory bean:

```
Object getInstance() {
....
String beanName= ????;
```

}

How I can receive name of bean that in this moment calls this method?
And second question: Do I have this method (getInstance) synchronized?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to implement [`BeanNameAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html). Then the container invokes the `setBeanName` methods and provide the name value. You can then set the beanName property in that method.